# Reduce stream into value with Rx scan operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a stream of location data from a real-time data source and I am trying to use the rx `scan` operator to reduce the stream and compute the distance traveled as new location changes are emitted.

The emitted values are in this format

```
{
  lat: 3.4646343,
  lng: 6.4343234,
  speed: 1.3353,
  heading: 279
}
```

And this is the processor

```
function distanceBetweenPoints (point, point2, unit: string = 'M') {
    const radlat1 = Math.PI * (point.lat / 180);
    const radlat2 = Math.PI * (point2.lat / 180);
    const theta = point.lng - point2.lng;
    const radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
    let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    if (unit == 'KM') { dist = dist * 1.609344; }
    if (unit == 'M') { dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000; }
    return dist;
}

const location$: Subject<LocationUpdate> = new Subject();

location$
    .pipe(
        map(location => {
            return { lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng };
        }),
        scan((x, y) => {
            return distanceBetweenPoints(x, y);
        }),
        takeUntil(locationUpdateEnd$)
    )
    .subscribe(distance => console.info('distance', distance));
```

I'm pretty sure that I am using the `scan` operator wrong because i'm seeing `Nan` and a numeric value in the output. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pairwise()` instead of `scan()`.

`pairwise()` will emit pairs of values: `[last_value, current_value]`, in your case, `[last_location, current_location]`.

Then `map()` that to your distance function.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `pairwise` operator

```
location$
        .pipe(
            map(coords => {
                return { lat: coords.lat, lng: coords.lng };
            }),
            pairwise(),
            scan((acc, coords) => {
                return acc + distanceBetweenPoints(coords[0], coords[1]);
            }, 0),
            takeUntil(endtrip$)
        )
        .subscribe(console.log);
```